# sending JWT authorization guzzle

Tags: symfony, jwt, guzzle

I'm trying to test this jwt authorization it works fine doing curl from console but when I try to use guzzle it gives me an empty response any help greatly appreciated

```
        $client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => 'http://localhost',
        'timeout' => 2.0,
    ]);

  $res =   $client->request('GET', '/api/private', [
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization'     => 'Bearer JWTTOKENHERE'
        ]
    ]);
```

I am also having trouble with this route /api/login_check it works fine with from php server but apache returns 404

```
curl -X POST http://localhos/api/login_check -d _username=johndoe -d _password=test
```

but with guzzle I get a 404 not found using [LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#prerequisites)

```
      $credentials = base64_encode('test@email.com:test');
      $res = $this->client->request('POST','/api/login_check',
          [
              'headers' => [
                  'Authorization' => ['Basic ' . $credentials]
              ]
          ]);
      dump($res);die();
```

Comment: figured out why I'm getting the  404 not found because I'm trying to hhit localhost but it is only working with localhost:8000 which does not seem to work with buiolt in php server curls always seems to time out so moved to local apache server

Comment: Are you sure the token is ok? How do you generate the token? Do you have any key with special characters?